# Work time tracking app?

Tags: time

I'm looking for time tracking app for linux that works automatically. Which means that you don't have to enter each new activity when you start it (as in hamster).
Best would be if it logs the app title and for how long it has been used. If it can track on which workspace you are too, even better. (unfortuantely that function of hamster doesnt work with compiz, otherwise it would have been great)

It shouldn't send the data to a server so RecueTime and TimeDoctor are no good either.

arrbtr seems to be all that, but it's too early version and shows stats just in the terminal now.

So is there anything else that i'm missing?